# Яндекс Диск. API - загрузка файлов

Tags: php, curl, яндекс-диск

Пытаюсь отправить файл с формы на облако Яндекс диска. Я понимаю, о чём ошибка, но не понимаю, как исправить. Мне не нужно загружать файл сначала на свой сервер, а с него на Яндекс, нужно сразу с устройства юзера на Яндекс, как это и задумано изначально.

Форма:

```
<form method="post" action="file.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
    <input name="ff" type="file">
    <input type="submit" value="отправить" name="uploadBtn">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
$token = 'TOKEN';

// Путь и имя файла на нашем сервере.
$fileName = $_FILES['ff']['name'];
$fileNameCmps = explode(".", $fileName);
$fileExtension = strtolower(end($fileNameCmps));
$file = md5(time() . $fileName) . '.' . $fileExtension;

echo $file;

// Папка на Яндекс Диске (уже должна быть создана).
$path = '/test/';

// Запрашиваем URL для загрузки.
$ch = curl_init('https://cloud-api.yandex.net/v1/disk/resources/upload?path=' . urlencode($path . basename($file)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: OAuth ' . $token));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$res = json_decode($res, true);
if (empty($res['error'])) {
// Если ошибки нет, то отправляем файл на полученный URL.
    $fp = fopen($file, 'r');

    $ch = curl_init($res['href']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($file));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($http_code == 201) {
        echo 'Файл успешно загружен.';
    } else {
    echo 'error2';

    }
}  else {
    var_dump($res['error']);
}
```

В итоге я получаю такой ответ

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл появляется на диске, но он некорректный, его нельзя открыть и посмотреть, но название, расширение передаются. Размер 0

Comment: Заменил `$fp = fopen($file, 'r');` на ` $fp = fopen($file, 'w+);` . Все предупреждения пропали, но с файлом всё так же осталось

Comment: base64_decode($data);

Comment: А что мешает их sdk юзать и не заморачиваться?

Comment: @Walfter мне нравятся ответы, подобные вашему. С таким же успехом можно написать "а что мешает выучить php наизусть и не задавать вопросы на stackoverflow?" Универсальный ответ в любом вопросе.

Comment: Я тут посмотрел ошибку... А вы файл как записываете на сервер? Почему у вас функция fopen ругается на отсутствие файла? И думаю путь лучше относительно корня ей отдавать что то типа `fopen(__DIR__.'/'.$file_name)` по этому у вас ворнинги пропадают когда вы ей  записывать(w+) разрешаете

Comment: Либо в fopen отдайте временный файл который получили от сервера в момент когда клиент отдал его вам

Comment: А в `файл успешно загружен` у вас заходит потому что вы условием проверяете правильно ли вы получили урлу для загрузки файла

Comment: @Walfter спасибо за ответ. Я помудрил и понял, а потом вычитал, что напрямую файл загружать нельзя, его надо сначала загрузить на сервер, а оттуда уже на облако. Но первоначальное дейсвтие не относится к АПИ яндекса никак. Спасибо ещё раз!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Файл получай из формы `$fp = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);`
и curl для записи используйте такой. Проверено, работает.

Форма:

```
<form method="post" action="yandex-file.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="file" type="file">
<input type="submit" value="отправить" name="uploadBtn">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if (empty($res['error'])) {

    $fp = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $res['href']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fp);
    $answer = curl_exec($ch);
    $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($http_code == 201) {
        echo 'Файл успешно загружен.';
    } else {
        echo 'error2';

    }
}  else {
    var_dump($res['error']);
}
```